# Is there any file size limitation to the Environment.getDataDirectory() space?

Tags: android, filesystems

I am using my app's 'Home' Directory on my Android /data/data/com.package.app/ to store a large file.

I was wondering if there is any size limit set on that directory?  I want to load an mp4 file from a server and store it locally in that directory.  The movie would be no more than 5 minutes.

Would I ever have problems with storing a large file?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the space in the /data/data directory would be limited based on what the phone has available. I believe most higher end phones ship with 1gb internal memory, lower end with like 512mb (kind of guessing, though). While I don't think there is a limit (other than phone's capacity) to how much you can store in the /data/ directory, I don't really think it is a good idea to store a relatively large file in there because it takes up space that is used for applications.